# Android - FragmentStatePagerAdapter: trigger swipe manually / disable swipe

Tags: android, button, triggers, swipe, fragmentstatepageradapter

Ok this basically what I'm trying to accomplish: I have a FragmentStatePagerAdapter and want occasionally to disable the swipe functionality and use buttons to go forward/backward.

A snipped from my code in MyFragmentStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter : (works fine with swipe, just for your orientiation)

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Item item = items.get(position/2);

    if (position%2 == 0) return new MyFragmentA(item, param1);
    if (position%2 == 1) return new MyFragmentB(item, param1);
    return null;
}
```

Any suggestions?
I just need to deactivate swipe and use 2 buttons...

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the Problem:

I didn't need to tamper with the Adapter (FragmentStatePagerAdapter).
The ViewPager has a Method setCurrentItem:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int)